# Power BI date slicer removes rows with blank date, is it possible to include them?

Tags: date, powerbi, filtering, slicers

I have a table of interactions between a Caller and a Recipient, with different Interaction_types. Most interaction types have a date but In_address_book does not.

When the date slicer includes the first possible date these In_address_book interactions are displayed. When a later start date is selected they all disappear.

Is there a way of changing this behaviour so they are 'always on', regardless of date? I could put a dummy date in the table for those rows, but then the same issue would happen if that date was not in the selected range.

Thanks for reading and in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Create new Table with:

```
Blank
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

2. make relation on Date[Month]
3. Make additional measure for blanks

> ```
> 194 =
> CALCULATE (
> SUM ( 'Table'[Sum] ),
> FILTER (
> ALL('Table'),
> 'Table'[State] IN { "on", "edit" } &&
> ISBLANK('Table'[date])
> )
> )
> ```

4. final measure

> ```
> 193 =
>     CALCULATE (
>     SUM ( 'Table'[Sum] ),
>     FILTER (
>     'Table',
>     'Table'[State] IN { "on", "edit" } &&
>     'Table'[date]<> BLANK()
>     )
>     )
>     + [194]
> ```